# How can TeamViewer work without modifying firewall/router settings?

Tags: remote-desktop, remote, remote-control

All remote desktop software that I know about needs to modify firewall settings and open ports.

How can Teamviewer work without modifying them? Does some alternative software exist that can also do remote control without modifying network settings?

Comment: "And, does exists some alternative software who"?? Please clarify that last line.

Comment: I think OP is looking for alternatives to Teamviewer which can do the same thing.

Comment: There are a lot of alternatives which use a server to set up the connection, so do not need open ports for incoming connections.  I use Citrix GoToAssist.  CrossLoop is another one.

Comment: Crossloop shutdown services since 2014, no longer available.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

TeamViewer on the remote PC maintains an idle connection to the TeamViewer proxy servers and waits for a connection request. After receiving it, a direct UDP connection can be set up; see [UDP hole punching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UDP_hole_punching).

Also try [pwnat](http://samy.pl/pwnat/).